# How to debug regression test binary pg_regress in postgreSQL?

Tags: c++, postgresql, macos, testing, lldb

I tried to debug pg_regress in postgreSQL using lldb on mac. However, when I run pg_regress using lldb, the test failed and reported: "failed to wait for subprocesses: Interrupted system call"

I customized a test schedule file which only has one test SQL. When I execute make check, the regression test passed.

Below is the output when debugging with lldb through Clion:

```
============== removing existing temp instance        ==============
============== creating temporary instance            ==============
============== initializing database system           ==============
============== starting postmaster                    ==============
running on port 60848 with PID 16262
============== creating database "regression"         ==============
CREATE DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
============== running regression test queries        ==============
test some_test               ... failed to wait for subprocesses: Interrupted system call

Process finished with exit code 2
```

Expected result should be

```
============== removing existing temp instance        ==============
============== creating temporary instance            ==============
============== initializing database system           ==============
============== starting postmaster                    ==============
running on port 60848 with PID 16262
============== creating database "regression"         ==============
CREATE DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
============== running regression test queries        ==============
test some_test               ... ok
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally did not find a way to use gdb to debug the multi-process pg_regress. The only way to debug it is to use the basic printf command. If anyone knows how to use gdb or lldb to trace multi-process program, please kindly provides an answer.